# Azure Keyvault 'unknown' access policy

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-keyvault

I added two accounts through powershell from devops yaml pipeline:

```
Set-AzKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName $keyVaultName -ObjectId $obj1 -PermissionsToSecrets Set,Get -BypassObjectIdValidation
Set-AzKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName $keyVaultName -ObjectId $obj2 -PermissionsToSecrets Set,Get -BypassObjectIdValidation
```

- $obj1 = ADF
- $obj2 = Pipeline Application identity

Obj1(ADF) came in 'Application' section of the access policy of Key Vault
But Obj2 came in 'Unknown'section why? 
Once Obj2 also came in 'Compound Identity' section .. not sure why

Comment: Could you make sure the two ObjectIds are correct? And could it work in cloudshell or in local?

Comment: I'm getting the same behavior. The object ID is fine, everything is fine, but it goes into a "unknown" category instead of application.

Comment: @AFP_555 did you solve the issue, did it listing as unknown cause any problem?

Answer (score 3):

If you are adding an Access Policy to Key Vault for an AAD application/service principal, make sure to use the ObjectId of the service principal, which is a different ObjectId than that of the application. You can use [Get-AzADServicePrincipal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/get-azadserviceprincipal?view=azps-4.4.0#examples) to retrieve the service principal and find its ObjectId.

Comment: I am using the objectid not the application client id and yet its still showing unknown. Even if I go into the key vault and look at the "JSON" it shows the same object id but if I create it via arm it fails to resolve but if I create it through the UI with the exact same guid and it outputs the exact same JSON it fails :(

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks! For a user managed identity, I had to use the `principal_id` column which put it into the known category.